# Ajax: best practise to update css menu

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need some guidance / advice on implementing menu state updates after an Ajax update of the main content div on my website.

I'm learning Ajax and got the basic site working. My pages have 3 sections - head, body, foot.  The body alone is refreshed by an Ajax request. I have a simple Bootstrap menu in the head, so I need to manually update it when a new page contents is loaded into the body to show the newly selected page. I do this by jQuery selector adding / removing an active class....

```
 // intercept main nav. menu links
 $(".nav a").click(function(e) { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var hr = $(this).attr('href');
    $('ul.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('ul.nav li a#'+id).closest('li').addClass('active');      
    // update link colours
    $('ul.nav li a').css('color', '#9d9d9d');
    $('ul.nav li a#'+id).css('color', '#fff');

    sendRequest(id, hr); // post off my Ajax request
    history.pushState({ident:id, href: hr}, "", hr);

    return false;   // prevent default
  });
```

I have similar code to intercept the browser back / forward buttons in  window.addEventListener to give an overall App feeling to my site. This works but I feel there may be a better way of doing it? Any advice or comments welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You already have the clicked element, no need to select it again with `ul.nav li a#'+id`. Other than that, looks OK

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed the  `$('ul.nav li a#'+id)`  now using `$(this)`